# forward parent event to child using query

Tags: jquery, events

My parent div contains a hidden form element (input):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.parent').on('click', function (event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).find('.child').trigger('click');
    });


    $('.child').on('click', function (event) {
      var theMsg = event.altKey ? 'true' : 'false';
       $('.parent span').html(theMsg);
    });

});
```

```css
.parent {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
}
.child {
    display:none;
}
.active {
    background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
    ALT: <span> </span>
    <input class='child'>
</div>
```

When my parent click handler is invoked, I pay attention to whether ALT key is pressed. I'm trying to trigger('click') for the hidden input element, and pass the altKey status along. Nothing I've tried makes that happen. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have sytax error for on click event. You have extra `)` after `click`. it should be:

```
$('.parent').on('click',function(event) {
 var theChild=$(this).find('.child');
 theChild.trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Yah, just a transcription error when I copied the code. Problem still exists.

Comment: @user1307065: can you reproduce the problem in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which browser or os platform you are using.  my code tested with ubuntu chromium.

In chromium browser Alt key used for selecting menu options.

for your reference :

[event.altKey not working in chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952260/event-altkey-not-working-in-chrome-and-ie)

so , you can go with Clt key or Shift key .

You can check this alse

[jQuery: How to catch keydown + mouse click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872498/jquery-how-to-catch-keydown-mouse-click-event)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  $(".parent").on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.altKey, e.ctrlKey, e.shiftKey);
    var theChild = $(this).find('.child');
    theChild.trigger('click');
  });

  $(".child").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('child');
  });

});
```

Please let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: the problem is that I can't find a way to get the ALT key in the child event. It works fine in the parent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10081246/5011051  . I think this will help your problem